# jQuery selection when using FancyBox and JW Player

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jwplayer, fancybox-2

I can get the following simple scenario to work:
A div on the page that when clicked will open a video using JW Player in an overlay window by FancyBox. Here is a stripped down code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="play_video" href="#" rel="/bin/video.mp4">Click to Watch Video</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".play_video").fancybox({
        content: '<div id="video_container" style="width:640px;height:381px;">Loading the player ... </div> ',
        afterShow: function()
            {
                var myVideo = $(".play_video").attr("rel");
                jwplayer("video_container").setup({
                    flashplayer: "/bin/player.swf",
                    file: myVideo,
                    width: 640,
                    height: 380,
                });
            }
    });
});
```

Here is my problem: if I want to display two DIVs each playing a different video how do I change the line

```
myVideo = $(".play_video").attr("rel")
```

to be dynamic and selecting the rel attribute of the right div. For example, the second div would look like:

```
<div>
    <a class="play_video" href="#" rel="/bin/another_video.mp4">Click to Watch a different Video</a>
</div>
```

I hope this is clear!  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `.attr()` method is that it gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, you may have to use the method `.each()`

To make it actually work without looping through your links, you could set the video reference inside the `href` attribute (the proper way to work) and tweak your code this way :

html

```
<a class="play_video" href="/bin/video.mp4">Click to Watch Video</a>
<a class="play_video" href="/bin/another_video.mp4">Click to Watch a different Video</a>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".play_video").on("click", function(){
   $.fancybox({
     content: '<div id="video_container" style="width:640px;height:381px;">Loading the player ... </div> ',
     afterShow: function(){
        var myVideo = this.href;
        jwplayer("video_container").setup({
          flashplayer: "/bin/player.swf",
          file: myVideo,
          width: 640,
          height: 380,
        }); // jwplayer setup
     } // afterShow
   }); // fancybox
   return false; // prevents default 
 }); // on
}); // ready
```

**NOTE**: `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

Comment: thank you for your response. It looks good, but there is a problem (which takes me back to the original problem) and that is "this" inside the afterShow() doesn't reference the original selection anymore so this.href returns null. I'd prefer to get your stated solution to work rather than using .each()

Comment: I got around it by saving the this.href in a variable before $.fancybox line and then using it in the afterShow(). However, I'd like to understand what "this" is referencing once it is in the afterShow: function() if anybody knows...thanks.

Comment: `this.href` works perfectly fine inside `afterShow` ... see **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRSUP/1/)**

Comment: you are correct, saving `this.href` in a variable before `$.fancybox` does the trick