# jwPlayer with fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jwplayer

Yes i know there is a bunch of similar questions but i didnt find them helpful for me.
I have situation like this: (with included jwplayer.js and all stuf about fancyBox)

```
< a class="jwVideo" href="" rel="group" > Preview < /a >


$(function() {    
    $(".jwVideo").click(function() {
           $.fancybox({
                'padding' : 0,
                'autoscale' : false,
                'transitionIn' : 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'title'  : this.title,
                'width'  : 640,
                'height' : 385,
                'href'    : this.href,
                'type'    : 'swf',
                'swf'   : { 'wmode':'transparent', 
                            'allowfullscreen':'true' 
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I need exactly this "template" of script so my question is how to adjust href attribute for playing video which is located on for example https://bla-bla.something1.amazon.com/video_1.mp4.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks JFK and Ethan on help, i solved problem so if anyone have similar problems here is the solution(worked for me):

Solution:

```
//html
<a class="jwVideo" href="https://bla-bla123.com/video_1.mp4" rel="group"> Preview </a>
//js
$(function() {
    $("a.jwVideo").click(function() {
        var myVideo = this.href; // Dont forget about 'this'

        $.fancybox({
            padding : 0,
            content: '<div id="video_container">Loading the player ... </div>',
            afterShow: function(){
                jwplayer("video_container").setup({ 
                    file: myVideo,
                    width: 640,
                    height: 385 
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: most closes try was with href="../js/jwplayer.flash.swf?file=https://bla-bla.something1.amazon.com/video_1.mp4."

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Comment: @JFK as i can see: fancyBox version: 2.1.4

Comment: @Ethan, sorry currently not.
In the end i only need working version, so doesn't matter which "template" is.

Comment: It would be nice to see a live example if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selection when using FancyBox and JW Player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336856/jquery-selection-when-using-fancybox-and-jw-player)

Comment: @Srle : I asked you about the version because the options in your first posted code are for v1.3.4, otherwise I would have referred you to a similar (duplicated) question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery library and fancybox with jwplayer version 6 you would do this

```
  $(function() { //this is much better then $(document).ready(function(){});

  $(".jwVideo").click(function(event) { //select class attribute jwVideo assigned to a tag
    var myVideo = $(this).attr('href'); // select the video link from a tag in jwVideo class

   //in the fancybox jwplayer setup code assign myVideo to file
    $.fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
        content: '<div id="video_container">Loading the player ... </div>',
        afterShow: function(){
            jwplayer("video_container").setup({ 
                file: ""+ myVideo +"",
    image: "",
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    fallback: 'false',
    autostart: 'true',
    primary: 'flash',
    controls: 'true'
            });
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default click..if this isn't here then browser will download the mp4 file instead of embedding jwplayer in fancybox
});


});
```